# Anime about an invasion of puppets

Tags: story-identification, anime

The anime is about a world invasion of puppets that kills humans. The protagonist is a girl who fights these puppets. In the end she realizes that the Queen looks exactly like her but with silver long hair. She also discovers that the Queen is a puppet made out of her mother's hair.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. What did the "puppets" look like. Were they controlled by someone else? What age is the protagonist? What is her relation to the queen? What was her name? How did she not realise the queen was a puppet? What was she the queen of? What was the setting (medieval, modern, futuristic)?

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be referring to [*Karakuri Circus*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/37447/Karakuri_Circus_TV). In it one of the main characters "Eleonore" fights a puppet based on (who I think is) her mother called "Francine"

> Karakuri Circus (Japanese: からくりサーカス, Hepburn: Karakuri Sākasu, "Mechanical Puppet Circus") is a Japanese manga series written and illustrated by Kazuhiro Fujita. It was serialized in Shogakukan's Weekly Shōnen Sunday magazine from July 1997 to June 2006, with its chapters collected into 43 tankōbon volumes.

> The story is centered around a young boy named Masaru Saiga, who inherits a massive fortune and aspires to become a puppeteer; Narumi Katō, a kung-fu expert who suffers from Zonapha syndrome (a strange illness that stops his breathing unless he makes people laugh); and Shirogane, a silver-haired woman and Masaru's caretaker who controls the puppet Harlequin. They must fight against the battling automatons (auto-mannequins) and save the world from the Zonapha syndrome.